# Switching windows hides other windows

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

Running Xubuntu 20.04.

It seems that I am only able to view one open window at a time. That is, when I switch windows (whether by Alt-tab, clicking in the panel, or opening a new window with a keyboard shortcut), all other windows get hidden.

When I Alt-tab, I can see the outline of where the next window will be. If I switch to it, it will appear as expected. But the previous window that was in focus will disappear.

I've also noticed that if I click on (what appears to be) the desktop, but an "open" window is in that space (the outlines of which are shown with Alt-tab, but is hidden because another window has focus), that window will appear. It seems that the windows are still "there", in that they are picked up as a layer between the desktop and the mouse, but they are not visible.

This is very disruptive because it means I can't tile two windows beside each other. Also in-application popups (for example the Find All dialog in IntelliJ) hide the parent window. Most frustratingly, this only started happening a couple days ago.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Window Manager Tweaks (`xfwm4-tweaks-settings`), in the 'Compositor' tab (also called 'Effects' in my native language), there is a slider controlling opacity of inactive windows. Set it to 100%, or at least >0%.

Comment: In my install, the setting was in Window Manager Tweaks under the Compositor tab.

Comment: @ColinStrong My install is not using English, and I attempted to translate the tab name. I'll edit to avoid confusion.